# Debug mode on Jenkins - Executing Windows batch command?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, jenkins

I have Windows Master & Windows node setup.
I am trying to execute a couple of windows batch commands on my Jenkins node on Windows but keep running onto a weird error.
If I run the same command on the command line from the same working directory the command executes perfectly fine.
Is there an equivalent of "#!/bin/bash -x" mode on windows or a debug mode I can see the output with?

Comment: Remove `echo off`.

Comment: I don't have echo off I just have command